# Size of a linspace output

Tags: python, numpy

If I execute the code below

```
x = np.linspace(1, 12, 5)
```

and if I display I get a result as

```
array([  1.  ,   3.75,   6.5 ,   9.25,  12.  ])
```

and if I do a shape() function on x then I get

```
(5,)
```

My question is that if we see the result then it is an array with one row and 5 columns then why do I see (5,) in shape. Shouldn't it be (1,5) 1X5 matrix

Comment: `result then it is an array with one row and 5 columns` - no it is a 1d vector with 5 entries. That's what `shape` tells you.

Answer (score 0):

The display does not represent whether it is columns or rows in the way that Matlab does (if that is what you were drawing your idea from).

To understand this try the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(1, 12, 5)
x_new = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
print(np.shape(x_new))
print(x_new)
```