# How do I change a row vector created with np.linspace into a column vector?

Tags: python, numpy

So far, I have the following:

`beta = np.linspace(1, 10, num = 10) / 55`

This returns the row vector:

`[0.01818182 0.03636364 0.05454545 0.07272727 0.09090909 0.10909091 0.12727273 0.14545455 0.16363636 0.18181818]`

I've tried using beta.transpose() but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linspace` produced a 1d array.  It does not have a transpose, or rather its transpose is the same shape - 1d.  `numpy`, in contrast to MATLAB, does not have row or column vectors.  It has arrays, which may have a wide variety of `shape`.

A 1d array with shape (4,):

```
In [218]: x
Out[218]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

One reshape - which may be called a 'row vector'

```
In [219]: x.reshape(1,4)
Out[219]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

A different reshape - a 'column vector', the transpose of the (1,4)

```
In [220]: x.reshape(4,1)
Out[220]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Another common way of making such an array:

```
In [221]: x[:,None]
Out[221]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you reformat the output of linspace to what you want :- [Size of a linspace output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965217/size-of-a-linspace-output)

The default output of linspace only has a single dimension (10,), I can't say this as an idiom but I believe row vectors (length, 1) and column vectors (1, length) are specific cases of a generalized 2D matrix in numpy, while (length,) is just a linear structure

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
print(a.shape)
(3,)
print(a.transpose().shape)
(3,)

b = np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(b.shape)
(1,3)
print(b.transpose().shape)
(3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
# 1
arr_col = arr.reshape(-1, 1).copy()

# 2
arr_col = arr[:, None].copy()
```